# Cannot load csv file using numpy loadtxt

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I cannot load a csv file using the numpy loadtxt function. There must be something wrong with the file format or something else. I am using anocanda notebook on macbook.

```
OSError: Macintosh HD⁩\\Users⁩\\binhao⁩\\Downloads⁩\\Iris_data.csv not found.


np.loadtxt("Macintosh HD⁩\\Users⁩\\binhao⁩\\Downloads⁩\\Iris_data.csv")
```

I tried a solution I found on stackflow involved using:

```
f = open(u"Macintosh HD⁩\\Users⁩\\binhao⁩\\Downloads⁩\\Iris_data.csv")

f = open("Macintosh HD⁩\\Users⁩\\binhao⁩\\Downloads⁩\\Iris_data.csv")
```

Above don't work -  No such file or directory error

Comment: "There must be something wrong with the file format" No, the error is telling you there is not file at that path. A formatting error would not result in this.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is the correct path. I have double checked.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time is due to some non-escaped charter, try to use raw string:

```
 r"Macintosh HD⁩\\Users⁩\\binhao⁩\\Downloads⁩\\Iris_data.csv"
```